# display "name" insted of "_id" in index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got "demand", "shift" and "parent" (this is going to be a baby sitter thingy).

Now the models look like this:

```
class Demand < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent
 belongs_to :shift
end
```

&

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :demands, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :shifts, :through => :demands
accepts_nested_attributes_for :demands, allow_destroy: true
# Returns fullname of parent
 def fullname
 "#{firstname} #{name}"
 end
end
```

&

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base 
 has_many :supps, :dependent => :destroy 
 has_many :nanns, :through => :supps

 has_many :demands, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :parents, :through => :demands 
end
```

If I now want to display a shift's description (a param of the shift table) instead of its _id, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is some code from the corresponding demands index view:

```
    <td><%= demand.parent.name %></td>
    <td><%= demand.demand %></td>
    <td><%= demand.shift.description %></td> <----THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', demand %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_demand_path(demand) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', demand, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

I think that I gave the models the correct has_many and belongs_to associations so I don't really find the mistake here. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I was unable to recreate your error, short of `demand.shift` being `nil`, hence the `undefined method 'description' for nil:NilClass`. Odds are you have missing the `shift_id` for that one `demand` in the database.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the `shift` is being assigned correctly (or saved). If you are using a version of Rails earlier than 5.0 (which does it automatically). You could add `validates_presence_of :parent, :shift` to your `Demand` class.

Comment: @MarcRohloff this actually seems to have done the trick :) Will continue testing this throughout the afternoon but if I don't comment another time, this is what worked! you might want to post this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You have a `demand` that has no associated `shift`.  If you want to identify which one in your table, replace...

```
  <td><%= demand.shift.description %></td>
```

with

```
  <td><%= demand.shift ? demand.shift.description : 'missing shift!' %></td>
```

The lines with missing shifts will now tell you that shift is missing.

Comment: thank you for your help! see the comment above by Marc Rohloff to see what did the trick